# which listener is first invoked to handle the event

Tags: java, actionlistener

When two or more objects are added as listeners for the same event, which listener is first invoked to handle the event?
The listener which is added first or the one which is added at last.
By event I mean the AWT events.

Comment: What event are we talking about?

Comment: Two Listeners of the same type both added to a single source? I do not believe the order is specified.

Comment: @assylias: Is the ArrayLists or LinkedLists the way to implement actionListeners?

Comment: I guess, what you are looking for is the answer of this MCQ question:  
Question: .When two or more objects are added as listeners for the same event, which listener is first invoked to handle the event?
A) The first object that was added as listener.
B) The last object that was added as listener.
c) There is no way to determine which listener will be invoked first.
D) It is impossible to have more than one listener for a given event.
Answer is C  There is no way to determine which listener will be invoked first.

Answer (score 3):

In Swing, these are often implemented using `EventListenerList` objects which preserve insertion order (they are backed by an array). However, it does not mean that listeners will be invoked in that order. As an example, this is the implementation in `AbstractButton`:

```
protected void fireStateChanged() {
    // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
    // those that are interested in this event
    for (int i = listeners.length-2; i>=0; i-=2) {
       //etc.
    }
}
```

So in that case it is actually processed in reverse order. That code complies with the [documentation of EventListenerList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) which gives a similar example.

The reason why it is traversed backwards is discussed in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559488/why-is-eventlistenerlist-traversed-backwards-in-firefooxxx).

All this is obviously implementation specific and should not be relied on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760267/java-swing-multiple-event-listeners-for-a-single-event-source-in-a-single-thread) is what you're looking for. In short, the firing order is indeterminate. If you wish to ensure a specific order perhaps try adding only one of the listeners and pass the event on to your other listeners in the desired order.